# Asp.net MVC4, how to use Role without using any provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use Role without any provider in asp.net MVC4 project.

I success making log in and out without provider.

but for the role, I don't know how to set it up.

this is my part of AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && myLogin(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

    //set Roles, how can I set role to users?
    if (HttpContext.User != null)
    {
        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
        {
        Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        }
        Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Administrator");

        //string[] roles = { "Moderator", "Administrator" };
        //HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.User.Identity, roles);
    }

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}

private bool myLogin(string userName, string password, bool persistCookie)
{
    if (userName == "root" && password == "root")
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

the //set Roles part is not working, the error message say,

**No user found was found that has the name "root".
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No user found was found that has the name "root".**

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
```

I want to control accessing this page using Role check,

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
      ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
      return View();
}
```

How can I define the role to user? for using filter on Action?

Comment: How do you expect to use roles without a provider?

Comment: is it not possible? there is no way just set role 'Administrator' to 'root' user simply??

Comment: I'm using Mysql, and I found the Mysql Membership Provider, but I do not want to follow the user table structure. so I just want to make very simple login/out and role function only for my project..

Comment: You can't use Roles without defining a RoleProvider in the Web.config, in the same way that you can't use Membership without a MembershipProvider.

Comment: What does it cost you to define a RoleProvider in your web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling `Roles.*` you are basically calling the underlying role provider that's registered in your web.config. If you don't want to use the default role provider (which works with SQL server) you could always [`write a custom role provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

All you need to do is write a custom implementation of the [`RoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, or at least the methods you intend to use:

```
public class MyRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{
    ... your implementation comes here
}
```

and then register your custom role provider in web.config to replace the default one:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyRoleProvider, MyAssembly" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```